# Trouble installing Boost on Windows 10

Tags: c++, boost

I'm stuck trying to install Boost (1.55) on Windows 10 (pro)
I have been following the instructions here [link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)
And I'm not sure what is supposed to happen at/after this stage:

```
   C:\Users\Sak09\Downloads\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2>b2 --build-dir="C:\Boost\" toolset=msvc --build-type= complete stage
warning: the --build-dir option was specified
warning: but Jamroot at '.'
warning: specified no project id
warning: the --build-dir option will be ignored
warning: No toolsets are configured.
warning: Configuring default toolset "msvc".
warning: If the default is wrong, your build may not work correctly.
warning: Use the "toolset=xxxxx" option to override our guess.
warning: For more configuration options, please consult
warning: http://boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/advanced/configuration.html
...found 580 targets...



C:\Users\Sak09\Downloads\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2>b2  toolset=msvc --build-type=complete stage
notice: could not find main target stage
notice: assuming it is a name of file to create.
don't know how to make <e>stage
...found 1 target...
...can't find 1 target...

C:\Users\Sak09\Downloads\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2>b2  --build-type=complete msvc stage
warning: No toolsets are configured.
warning: Configuring default toolset "msvc".
warning: If the default is wrong, your build may not work correctly.
warning: Use the "toolset=xxxxx" option to override our guess.
warning: For more configuration options, please consult
warning: http://boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/advanced/configuration.html
notice: could not find main target stage
notice: assuming it is a name of file to create.
don't know how to make <e>stage
...found 1 target...
...can't find 1 target...
```

Any help is very much appreciated. I'm trying to setup dev stuff in Windows after a decade and I'm really struggling with this.

Comment: Did you launch it from Development Command Prompt?

Comment: Yes. Also tried as administrator.

Comment: You can actually omit that build dir part completely. Also there should be no space after `=` in `--build-type= complete` try `bjam threading=multi toolset=msvc-14.1 --stagedir="./stage" --build-type=complete`

Comment: Tried without the build dir part, please find the new outputs as part the question above, was following the instructions in the link verbatim

Comment: Which version ( and release#) of MS VC++ ?

Comment: Run `bootstrap` followed by `.\b2` from `C:\Users\Sak09\Downloads\boost_1_55_0\boost_1_55_0` within a Developer Command Prompt window. Those are the only required commands; you should leave experimenting with additional options until after you've successfully built Boost using the basic options.

Comment: Its MS Visual studio 15.7.4 community version

Comment: Also, Boost 1.55 is very old so you might get warnings about an unrecognized toolset with VS2017. You should download a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same instructions with Boost version 1.60 and it just worked. So yeah some compatibility issue with VS2017 and older versions of Boost. Thanks everyone for the suggestioons.

Comment: 1.60 is also very old. 1.67 is the latest, see https://www.boost.org/users/download/